# EF error on save: A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to save multiple records of my entity SubEntity of the same time within the same type, but I get the error "EF error on save: A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values".

SubEntity looks like this:

```
public class SubEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SubEntity>
{
    public SubEntityMap()
    {
        //Primary key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        //Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("SubEntity", "dbo");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.UpdateUser).HasColumnName("UpdateUser");
        Property(t => t.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate").IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.UpdateDate).HasColumnName("UpdDate").IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.Del).HasColumnName("Del").IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.MainEntityId).HasColumnName("MainEntityId").IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.ValueRefId).HasColumnName("ValueRefId").IsRequired();

        //Relationships
        HasRequired(t => t.MainEntity)
            .WithMany(t => t.SubEntities)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.MainEntityId);

        HasRequired(t => t.Ref)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(d => d.ValueRefId);
    }
}
```

The related entities' mapping are:

```
public class MainEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MainEntity>
{
    public MainEntityMap()
    {
        // Prim`enter code here`ary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("MainEntity");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");


    }
}

public class RefMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Ref>
{
    public RefMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Ref", "dbo");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id")
            .IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.Code).HasColumnName("Code")
            .IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

There is also a type SourceEntity that is similar to MainEntity and that also defines a relationship 1:N to a table that is almost an exact copy of SubEntity.
(they define the 2 different steps of our business process, so we had to duplicate the main entities that correspond to each step, and also their collections).

The code below copies the subEntity elements from the SourceEntity (step 1 of the business process) to MainEntity (step 2 of the business process)

```
public void CopyToSubEntity(SourceEntity sourceEntity, MainEntity mainEntity, string userName)
{
    var sourceEntitySubEntities = GetSubEntities(sourceEntity.id);
    var mainEntitySubs = new List<SubEntity>();

    foreach (var sourceEntitySubEntity in sourceEntitySubEntities )
    {
        var subEntity = new subEntity
        {
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            mainEntity = mainEntity,
            ValueRef = sourceEntitySubEntity.ValueRef
        };
        _subEntityRepository.Add(subEntity);
    }
}
```

If I do a save changes for each of those, I can get it to work, but I want to understand what's happening. The exception is not giving any info whatsoever, besides the message A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values.
Any suggestion?

EDIT:

I've been debugging the EF code and the root of the issue is in the EF's method

```
private Dictionary<CompositeKey, PropagatorResult> ProcessKeys(
    UpdateCompiler compiler, List<PropagatorResult> changes, Set<CompositeKey> keys)
{
    var map = new Dictionary<CompositeKey, PropagatorResult>(
        compiler.m_translator.KeyComparer);

    foreach (var change in changes)
    {
        // Reassign change to row since we cannot modify iteration variable
        var row = change;

        var key = new CompositeKey(GetKeyConstants(row));

        // Make sure we aren't inserting another row with the same key
        PropagatorResult other;
        if (map.TryGetValue(key, out other))
        {
            DiagnoseKeyCollision(compiler, change, key, other);
        }

        map.Add(key, row);
        keys.Add(key);
    }

    return map;
}
```

When I step through the code the first time, map is empty and key is added to map.

The second time around, map.TryGetValue returns true.

The content of map is, {Preserve:Quote:{Id=Key:id21:ord0:0, Field1=ForeignKey:id8:ord1:459, Field2=ForeignKey:id10:ord2:0, etc}}

the content of key is {Key:id61:ord0:0}

EF defines its own equality comparer:

```
private class CompositeKeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<CompositeKey>
{
    private readonly KeyManager _manager;

    internal CompositeKeyComparer(KeyManager manager)
    {
        DebugCheck.NotNull(manager);

        _manager = manager;
    }

    // determines equality by comparing each key component
    public bool Equals(CompositeKey left, CompositeKey right)
    {
        // Short circuit the comparison if we know the other reference is equivalent
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // If either side is null, return false order (both can't be null because of
        // the previous check)
        if (null == left
            || null == right)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Debug.Assert(
            null != left.KeyComponents && null != right.KeyComponents,
            "(Update/JoinPropagator) CompositeKey must be initialized");

        if (left.KeyComponents.Length
            != right.KeyComponents.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < left.KeyComponents.Length; i++)
        {
            var leftValue = left.KeyComponents[i];
            var rightValue = right.KeyComponents[i];

            // if both side are identifiers, check if they're the same or one is constrained by the
            // other (if there is a dependent-principal relationship, they get fixed up to the same
            // value)
            if (leftValue.Identifier
                != PropagatorResult.NullIdentifier)
            {
                if (rightValue.Identifier == PropagatorResult.NullIdentifier
                    ||
                    _manager.GetCliqueIdentifier(leftValue.Identifier) != _manager.GetCliqueIdentifier(rightValue.Identifier))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (rightValue.Identifier != PropagatorResult.NullIdentifier
                    ||
                    !ByValueEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(leftValue.GetSimpleValue(), rightValue.GetSimpleValue()))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

How does the fact that EF is saying they are the same record make sense?

Comment: What type database are you using?  Database may not support more than one thread.

Comment: I should have said that. It’s MS SQL and the same operation works fine for other entities

Comment: You are trying to do parallel linq which is not thread safe.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/201f5ce2-7213-452b-8dd9-c4573535c5b0/problem-when-adding-object-in-entity-framework-using-parallelforeach?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: Can you add an example code for how you are adding the multiple entities?

Comment: There is no parallel statement involved

Comment: @StevePy: added the details in the question

Comment: *"I want to understand what's happening"* Then please provide [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Based on the usage code added I believe the root cause will be something around entity references across contexts, or setting reference IDs as opposed to entities.

Looking at this code:

```
public void MoveMainEntityCodesToSubEntity(MainEntity mainEntity, SubEntity subEntity)
{
    var mainEntityClasses = _mainEntityClassRetriever.GetBymainEntityId(mainEntity.id);
    subEntity.subEntityClasses = new List<SubEntityClass>();

    foreach (var mainEntityClass in mainEntityClasses)
    {
        var subEntityClass = new subEntityClass
        {
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            ValueRefId = mainEntityClass.ValueRefId
        };

        subEntity.subEntityClasses.Add(subEntityClass);
    }       
}
```

... there are a few details that are a bit confusing. You appear to be passing in Entities into this method, a parent, and a child which I am assuming is a child that is already associated to that parent. With the Parent ID you are going to the context to load parent entities by ID. Q1: Why is this call expecting to return multiple parents? Is it that your chosen retriever pattern is returning `IQueryable<MainEntity>`? Or are you using some form of generic pattern for all retrievers so you return `IEnumerable<MainEntity>`?

```
subEntity.subEntityClasses = new List<SubEntityClass>();
```

this line here is a concern. If subEntity is a tracked Entity, you should never clear it's collection references by setting to a new List. To do a full delete & replace you should use .Clear() on the collection. However, since you are looking at updating data relationships this is also probably not advisable, instead load the child collection and then determine what items have been added vs. removed by comparing it against the data passed in.

The entity defintions don't really match up with what your code appears to be trying to do, but it looks like you want to move sub entities from one main entity to another main entity. (Since sub-entity doesn't have a collection of sub-entities)

The first issue is what context were these two passed in, and the child collections of each. By setting one tracked entity's child collection to a new instance of a list you do *not* delete those child references in the database. EF can/will still be tracking the children against the old parent. I believe this is why you will be getting the error you are getting.

assuming that source and target were loaded by the same context:

```
public void MoveMainEntityCodes(MainEntity source, MainEntity target)
{
    // if lazy loading is enabled...
    var subEntities = new List<SubEntity>(source.SubEntityClasses);
    // or if lazy loading is disabled and you don't know if the sub entities were loaded.
    //if(source.SubEntityClasses == null || !source.SubEntityClasses.Any())
    //    _context.Entity(source).Collection(x => x.SubEntityClasses).Load();
    //var subEntities = new List<SubEntity>(source.SubEntityClasses);

    foreach(var subEntity in subEntities)
    {
       source.SubEntityClasses.Remove(subEntity);
       target.SubEntityClasses.Add(subEntity);
       subEntity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now; // if you want to refresh the created date.
    }
}
```

What this currently doesn't account for is whether the target entity could already have sub entities and what should happen to those to avoid duplicates. Generally I prefer to take an approach that checks both source and target for diffs (items to add vs. items to remove) and then add/remove based on that.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Although the method name isn't ideal, what we are trying to accomplish it to copy collections from the main entity to the sub entity. The sub entity was created right before the method call, hence its collections will be empty (that's why we create a new list)

Comment: Ok, so is it a different collection than the sub-entity itself belongs to, because that was what was confusing me. Main has a collection of subs, then wants to "move" those subs to one of those nominated subs? Or is it more a case of main has a collection of X and a collection of Subs, and subs have a Collection of X so you want to move the X collection from main to one of the subs?